# Padding an array with zeroes in fortran without using loops

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran95

I have two arrays, and I want to compare their sizes and add trailing zeroes to whichever array is shorter.

eg- For arrays -

```
y1=(/ 1,2,3 /)
y2=(/ 1,2,3,4,5 /)
```

The final result should be -

```
y1=(/ 1,2,3,0,0 /)
y2=(/ 1,2,3,4,5 /)
```

I am very new to Fortran, and from what I know till now, this can be done like this:-

```
integer, allocatable :: y1(:),y2(:)
integer :: l1,l2,i
.
.
.
! some code to generate y1 and y2 here
.
.
.
l1=size(y1)
l2=size(y2)

if (l1>l2) then
    do i=l2+1,l1
        y2(i)=0
    enddo
else if (l2>l1) then
    do i=l1+1,l2
        y1(i)=0
    enddo
endif
```

I want to know if there is a better way of doing this, preferably one that doesn't involve loops, since the actual problem I am working on might have huge vectors

Comment: First you have to re-allocate the shorter array. Is it allocatable? How is it defined?

Comment: Yes, they are allocatable. I will edit the question. I thought the variable declarations were unnecessary

Comment: keep in mind that in modern Fortran (since 2003 I think) you can use the square-bracket array constructors like: `y1=[ 1,2,3 ]`, instead of the uglier older `(//)`.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you. I am using an f95 extension though. That's all I know till now

Comment: @Vladimir, modern Fortran supports allocation on assignment.  OP does not need to re-allocate the shorter-array.

Comment: @Steve Well, reallocation on assignment is still reallocation for my money. And I was well aware of this possibility when writing my comment.

Comment: @Vladimir, We can only go by what was written in your original comment.  It indicates that OP would need to do manual re-allocation himself/herself.  There is no hint that the compiler can do the re-allocation for OP.

Comment: @Steve Reallocate, there is no mention of doing it manually. I repeat, I am well aware of autemoatic reallocation as shown many times on this very server. There very larger unknowns at the moment of the comment and it wasn't clear at all whether the arrays are even allocateble in that scope or, for example, dummy arguments of some sort. More had to be found out before being able to advise *how* to do the reallocation.

Comment: @Vladimir, it is most certainly implied that one must do it manaully.  You wrote _First, you have to re-allocate..._  **You** does not refer to a compiler. It refers to OP.  Perhaps, you meant to write _First, the shorter array needs to be re-allocated_  This, then, permits either manual re-allocation or (re-)allocation on assignment.

Comment: There is really no point teaching me that there is automatic reallocation. I am using it almost every day. Sorry, but no. I had it in mind as a posibility when writing the comment.

Comment: @Vladimir, I'm not trying to teach you about re-allocation.  It seems that I'm trying to teach you basic English.  _First, YOU have to re-allocate the shorter array._ has very clear meaning in the English language.

Comment: @Yuki.kuroshita You don't need to change the file extension to something other than".f90". Just use the modern Fortran syntax on a modern Compiler (Intel, IBM, GNU, ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
y1 = RESHAPE(y1,SHAPE(y2),pad=[0])
```

No explicit loops.  As @VladimirF commented the shorter array has to be re-allocated, this approach leaves it to the compiler and the run-time to take care of that.

If you are concerned about the performance of this approach, or concerned about its performance *wrt* a version using explicit loops, and concerned about how the performance scales with the sizes of arrays, then run some tests.  I wouldn't be surprised to find that explicit reallocation and a loop or two are faster than this 'clever' approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't tested anything on any real data set yet. But thank you for your advice. I will test both methods to see which one is better in terms of performance

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for, so I thought I should accept it. It does exactly what I wanted, pad the array. There might be other methods but this is technically exactly what I asked. I will check the performance though.

Comment: I actually ran a test on different sizes of datasets from a 1000 to 50000000, with a difference between the sizes of the arrays ranging from 10 to 9000000. In general, in all of my tests, explicitly allocating, deallocating and looping is 60% faster approx.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  It confirms my general view that explicit loops are faster than the neat whole-array alternatives, but it's always nice to have data.

Comment: This is kind of counter intuitive for me. I mean I used to think whole array alternatives are faster. I mean in codes I tested in MATLAB, they seemed faster

Comment: @Yuki.kuroshita: In many interpreted languages like matlab, python/numpy, R, array operations are faster because then you avoid the interpreter overhead of explicit loops. In Fortran, it's all compiled to machine code, so you should just use whatever is clearest. Array syntax is a godsend, and makes many common operations simple and short, but you don't need to do some super-tricky stuff just to avoid falling of a performance cliff. If an algorithm is clearer to express as an explicit loop, just do that.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @janneb

Answer (score 2):

If you are only concerned with rank 1 arrays, using `SHAPE` and `RESHAPE` is overkill.  Simply use Fortran's array constructor features.  You also can use modern Fortran's allocation-on-assignment feature, so you do not need to re-allocate the shorter array.

```
program foo
  implicit none
  integer, allocatable :: y1(:),y2(:)
  integer :: l1,l2,i
  y1 = [1, 2, 3]
  y2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  l1 = size(y1)
  l2 = size(y2)
  if (l1 > l2) y2 = [y2, [(0,i=1,l1-l2)]]
  if (l2 > l1) y1 = [y1, [(0,i=1,l2-l1)]]
  print '(10(I0,1X))', y1
  print '(10(I0,1X))', y2
end program foo
```

Comment: There is an even shorter program with maybe little more computational work.  Remove `if (l1 > l2)` and `if (l2 > l1)`.  The resulting array constructors with implied-do loops will do the right thing.